React Code Block Rendering Issues with Prism.js in Large Messages
Problem
I'm building a message parser component in React that handles different types of content including code blocks. When the code content is very large (hundreds of lines), the syntax highlighting stops working and sometimes the component completely fails to render any subsequent code blocks.
Code
Here's a simplified version of my current implementation:
const MessageParser = ({ message }) => {
  const messageRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!messageRef.current) return;

    // Handle code highlighting
    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      try {
        Prism.highlightAllUnder(messageRef.current);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Prism highlighting error:', error);
      }
    });
  }, [message]);

  const renderItem = (item, index) => {
    if (item.coding) {
      const language = getLanguage(item.coding);
      const formattedCode = item.coding
        .replace(/\\n/g, '\n')
        .trim();
      
      return (
        
          
            
              {formattedCode}
            
          
        
      );
    }
    // other render logic
  };

  return (
    
      {parseMessage(message)}
    
  );
};

Expected Behavior

All code blocks should render with proper syntax highlighting
Performance should remain stable regardless of code block size
Subsequent code blocks should continue to render even after a large code block

Actual Behavior

When code blocks are very large (>1000 lines), syntax highlighting fails
After encountering a large code block, subsequent code blocks sometimes fail to render
Performance degrades significantly with large code blocks
Sometimes the entire component becomes unresponsive

Environment

React 18.2.0
Prism.js (latest version)
Modern browsers (Chrome 120, Firefox 121, Safari 17)

What I've Tried

Wrapping the Prism.highlight call in requestAnimationFrame
Using useEffect to handle highlighting
Adding error boundaries around code blocks
Implementing basic error handling for the highlighting process

Question
What's the best way to handle very large code blocks in React while maintaining:

Proper syntax highlighting
Good performance
Reliable rendering of all code blocks

Is there a recommended approach for chunking or virtualizing large code blocks with Prism.js? Or should I consider a different syntax highlighting library for better performance with large code blocks?
What I've Tried

Wrapping the Prism.highlight call in requestAnimationFrame
Using useEffect to handle highlighting
Adding error boundaries around code blocks
Implementing basic error handling for the highlighting process

Question
What's the best way to handle very large code blocks in React while maintaining:

Proper syntax highlighting
Good performance
Reliable rendering of all code blocks

Is there a recommended approach for chunking or virtualizing large code blocks with Prism.js? Or should I consider a different syntax highlighting library for better performance with large code blocks?
